# Conflicting information on Qualcomm quick-charge 3.0 standard

Tags: battery-charging, charging, battery-chemistry

Out of many fast charging protocols, Qualcomm quick-charge 1.0/2.0/3.0/4.0/4+ is a prominent one. I tried to find the specification of quick-charge 3.0 protocol.

However, the material spread across the Internet is conflicting and confusing.

**Disagreement in max voltage, current, power:**

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Charge): Max current: 2.6A or 4.6A, Max power: 18W (9V*2A), Voltage: 3.6V-20V, dynamic with 200 mV increments
- [Belkin](https://www.belkin.com/us/resource-center/quick-charge): Max current: 2A or 3A, Max power: 36W, Voltage: 3.6V-12V
- [Qualcomm](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/quick-charge-30): Max current: 2.6A or 4.6A, Max voltage: 22V

**Voltage levels:**

[Android Authority](https://www.androidauthority.com/quick-charge-3-0-explained-643053/) says,

> The major new feature with 3.0 is INOV (Intelligent Negotiation for
>   Optimum Voltage), which allows for a fined tuned power output and a
>   more optimized charging cycle. Firstly, different batteries require
>   different charging voltages. Version 2.0 supported four modes at
>   varying power levels, 5 volts/2amps, 9V/2A, 12V/1.67A, and a 20 volt
>   option. Quick Charge 3.0’s INOV communicates with the device to
>   request any voltage between 3.2V and 20V at 200mV increments, allowing
>   for a wider selection of voltages.

The above sounds like there are numerous voltage levels supported in steps of 200mV between 3.2V and 20V. However, the specification of [Mi India Standard Charger](https://store.mi.com/in/item/3173700004) (MDY-08-EW), which is a [Qualcomm quick-charge 3.0 certified](https://www.qualcomm.com/media/documents/files/quick-charge-device-list.pdf) charger, speaks something else:

> Output current: DC 5V=3A / 9V=2A / 12V=1.5A

It seems like the voltage levels are fixed, just like quick-charge 2.0 standard.

My questions/confusions regarding quick-charge 3.0 are:

- Where do I get official Qualcomm quick-charge 3.0 standard specification?
- Are the voltage levels fixed or stepped in 200mV?
- What are corresponding current and power ratings?

Comment: You're confusing system standard (Quick-Charge) specifications with what actual devices can do. That's like saying that you can legally drive 400 km/h and finding it contradicting that a VW Golf's datasheet says it won't go any faster than 220 km/h.

Comment: If the protocol defined numerous stepped levels of voltages and the device offers only three, how come does it even follow the standard?

Comment: Also, Wikipedia and Belkin disagree in max/min current, voltage and power ratings as well

Comment: Because the standard allows that. It's absolutely common for standards to specify "does one or multiple of the following things".

Comment: I want to convince myself by reading the standard specification, if available publicly.

Comment: Wikipedia is a random collection of things people wrote down and not an original source. If the original source isn't given in wikipedia, then that would be a case for `[citation needed]`. Wikipedia is NEVER an original source of information. Wikipedia explicitly forbids adding original information. Belkin doesn't write standards, they produce products, see my first comment.

Comment: Since QC is a Qualcom-proprietary technology, I believe you simply *won't* get a public specification. The way to get a compatible product is to sign an NDA with Qualcom, buy a million Qualcom ICs, pay them to consult you and pay them so that you can use the Quick-Charge copyrighted identifiers.

Comment: On the other hand, the USB Power Delivery standard _is_ public, and does about the same thing. If you're in a situation that lets you choose, perhaps look into that instead?